How to export Excel VBA script as .XLAM Add-in?
I want to distribute my VBA script as .XLAM add-in.
My VBA-script contains one based on worksheet event:
 Private Sub Woorksheet_Change (ByVal Target as Range)
 ....
 End sub

Unfortunately, button "Compile VBA project" disabled, why?

And when I try to export my VBA script as Script.XLAM I receive just source code started from:
Version 1.0 Class
BEGIN
   MultiUser = -1 'True
END
ATTRIBUTE VB_NAME=....

If I try to import this Script.XLAM as Add-in to another Workbook I get error "Excel can not open the file script.xlam because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify..."

I can not understand what going wrong?

"Compile VBA project" is disabled when no code change was done since the last compile.

@FunThomas. Thanks, I know this trick. Now Again I changed my code, restart Excel and button "Compile VBA project" still disabled.

Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve? I have the feeling that you misunderstand the idea of an AddIn. An AddIn is loaded automatically when Excel starts and has no visible sheets. Therefore, an WorkSheet_Change-event of an AddIn makes not much sense, it will not serve as Eventhandler for any other sheet. If you want to create an AddIn, you need to save the whole workbook as XLAM

VBA compiles the code automatically when you open the workbook or when needed (eg when you modify code and run it without using the compile command)

Compile VBA project is disabled when the code is already compiled, i.e., 'everything is OK'. This could also mean that you have no code in the workbook.

BTW, you can export modules only to .bas or .cls files. You could copy/rewrite the code to a standard module and export it to a .bas file and import it when necessary. Then you could call it from the sheet module with something like Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Taget As Range): MyChange Target: End Sub where MyChange is the name of the code in the standard module. As FunThomas already mentioned, share what you're trying to do in more detail so we can offer some practical solutions.

Thanks, maybe both of you are right. I have created special VBA script, what doing some transformation data what user entered to cell, for example changing some value, forbid enter double value and more. Now script working fine, time to deploy it. I want to pass my script to financial accounting department. I want that any staff workers in financial department have easy access to my VBA script, but can not change my code and maybe even can not see it. For me, best way is create XLAM extension and put my script to trusted location as XLAM. Or this is wrong idea?

@FunThomas, yes, Whole workbook saved to XLAM correctly. Not only VBA script. Please add your advice as solution. In other case - what best way to pass my script to staff in financial department? Maybe my idea with XLAM not a best way? What way better?

Watch: Excel VBA Introduction Part 33 - Creating Add Ins.  The code in the image is more of a snippet than something I'd put in an Add-In.  The reason being is that it needs to be applied to specific use cases.  You would want this functionality applied to all  worksheets,  Would you?  BTW, i should be declared as Long.

Ups. @TinMan, thanks

If you want (from an add-in for example) to be able to capture events in other workbooks, you need Application events - e.g. see: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/events/excel-application-level-events.htm

Final solution take Tim Williams Events on XLAM Add-in not connected to Workbook
 'Class module with name AppEvents
 Option Explicit
 Private AppEvt As AppEvents
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Set AppEvt = New AppEvents
     Set AppEvt.App = Application
     MsgBox "Workbook_Open"
 End Sub

 'ThisWorkbook
 Option Explicit
 Public WithEvents App As Application
 Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     MsgBox "App_WorksheetChange"
 End Sub


